# TRIGGER DELETE with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

These are the relevant tables for this question:

```
Employee (EID, FirstName, LastName) - father
ConstructorEmployee (EID, CompanyName, SalaryPerDay) - son
Project (PID)
ProjectsConstructorEmployees (EID, PID, ...)
```

I would like to create a trigger that whenever someone deletes a project, it will delete all constructor employees from the employee table (and with cascade, the matching constructor employee), that is working **only** in the deleted project.

That means that if employee 1 works at projects 1 and 2, employee 2 works only at project 2, after deleting project 2, employee 2 will be deleted while 1 will not.

This is what I've tried so far but I'm missing the only one project part.

```
------- 1 -------
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProject
AFTER DELETE 
ON Project 
AS
    DELETE FROM Employee
    WHERE E.EID == (SELECT EID 
                    FROM ConstructorEmployee as CE
                    WHERE CE.PID == (SELECT PID FROM deleted)) 
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your delete in a `BEGIN`/`END` block.

In your trigger, you can use the `IN` comparison operator to include a query that returns the list of the employee ids to delete.

To build the id list, you want to lookup all employees that did work on that project in table `ProjectsConstructorEmployees`, and then filter out all those who are currently recorded on another project, using a correlated query and a `NOT EXIST` clause.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProject
AFTER DELETE ON Project AS
BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM Employee
    WHERE E.EID IN (
        SELECT PCE.EID 
        FROM 
            DELETED DEL
            INNER JOIN ProjectsConstructorEmployees PCE ON PCE.PID = DEL.PID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ProjectsConstructorEmployees
            WHERE EID  = PCE.EID
            AND   PID != DEL.PID
        )
    )
END
```

NB : for your logic to make sense, you must add another step after this one, to unconditionnaly delete all projects-related records from table `ProjectsConstructorEmployees`. Else employee that ever worked on two different projects will never go away.

```
DELETE FROM ProjectsConstructorEmployees WHERE PID = (SELECT PID FROM DELETED)
```

Answer (score -1):

HOPE THIS HELPS.

```
   CREATE TABLE Employee(EID INT,FirstName varchar(500),LastName varchar(50))
```

GO

```
   CREATE TABLE ConstructorEmployee(EID INT,CompanyName varchar(500),SalaryPerDay bigint)
```

GO

```
   CREATE TABLE Project(PID INT)
```

GO

```
  CREATE TABLE ProjectsConstructorEmployees(EID int ,PID INT)
```

GO

```
   INSERT INTO Employee
   SELECT 1,'MANI','KANDAN'
   UNION
   SELECT 2,'RAM','CHARAN'
   UNION
   SELECT 3,'RAGU','NATH'
```

GO
       INSERT INTO ConstructorEmployee
       SELECT 1,'HST',20
       UNION
       SELECT 2,'RRR',50
       UNION
       SELECT 3,'FRT',90

GO

```
  INSERT INTO PROJECT 
  SELECT 9
  UNION
  SELECT 10  
  UNION
  SELECT 13
```

GO
      INSERT INTO ProjectsConstructorEmployees
      SELECT 1,9
      UNION
      SELECT 1,10
      UNION
      SELECT 2,13
      UNION
      SELECT 3,9
      UNION 
      SELECT 3,10

GO

```
 SELECT * FROM Employee
 SELECT * FROM ConstructorEmployee
 SELECT * FROM Project
 SELECT * FROM ProjectsConstructorEmployees
```

GO

```
 CREATE TRIGGER PROJ_DEL
 ON Project
 FOR  DELETE
 AS
 DECLARE @A TABLE (A INT)
 INSERT INTO @A 
 SELECT * FROM DELETED
 DELETE S FROM ConstructorEmployee S WHERE EID IN(
 SELECT D.EID FROM ProjectsConstructorEmployees D JOIN (
 SELECT A.* FROM ProjectsConstructorEmployees A INNER JOIN @A  B ON
 ( A.PID=B.A) INNER JOIN ConstructorEmployee C ON (A.EID = C.EID))F ON 
 (D.EID=F.EID)
 GROUP BY D.EID 
 HAVING COUNT(D.EID)=1)
```

GO

```
  DELETE FROM PROJECT WHERE PID=10---EID 10 MAPPED TO MORE THAN ONE PROJ SO 
  IT WILL NOT ALLOW FOR DELETE

  DELETE FROM PROJECT WHERE PID=13---EID 13 MAPPED TO  ONLY ONE PROJ SO IT 
  WILL  ALLOW FOR DELETE
```